# min-width and position fixed not working

Tags: html, css

I have two columns where the left one has a dynamic width, and the right one has a google map with position: fixed.

The left column has a min-width value and when the window is resized, it does not work.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WWLd9/61/

**HTML**:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<section id="panel_contenedor">
</section>
<section id="mapa_contenedor">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**:

```
#panel_contenedor {
width: 50%;
min-width:300px;
}
#mapa_contenedor {
width:50%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
}
#map-canvas {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a `min-width:50%;` to the `#left` section and change `min-width:200px;` to `min-width:50%;` to the `#right`. It seems that, in all case, both section adjusts accordingly and the blue section doesn't hide the red anymore.

**Edit:**

`position:fixed` is relative to the html element of the DOM. That's the reason why you're seeing the map even if the min-width was set to 300px.

To fix it, here's what I tried:

I replace the google map with an Iframe (you can always set it up like you want).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <section id="panel_contenedor">
        todo texto bien elaborado ha de presentar siete características:<br><br><br><br>Ha de ser coherente, <br><br><br><br>es decir, centrarse en un solo tema, de forma que las diversas ideas<br><br><br><br> vertidas en él han de contribuir a la creación de una idea global.
    </section>
    <section id="mapa_contenedor">
        <iframe width="600" height="300" marginheight="0" 
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;q=loc:{address} {number}@{latitude},{longitude}&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near" 
        frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">
        </iframe>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#panel_contenedor {
    width: 50%;
    min-width:300px;
    float:left;
}

#mapa_contenedor {
    max-width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}

#map-canvas {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#main{
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    display:inline-block;
    /*overflow-x:hidden;*/
}
```

I've put in comment `/*overflow-x:hidden;*/`. It only adds a scroll bar if you need one when the window is reduced. The `display:inline-block;` show both sections on the same line. We just need to add a `float:left` to the left section and a `float:right` to the right section. I've put them in a `#main` container to adjust the size to the full window.

Comment: Thanks Freelex, but I edit the question to be understood better